# Powershell REST API call issue: how to understand?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, rest

VS2019 Rest service console app.

I call my Rest service via Powershell script.
It uses try-catch and during the call I receive the error

Request Error
BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}

Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

I see that no service method call but the error. How to understand the reason?

That is method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/createdbnode", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Message CreateDbNode(string name, bool is_enabled, DbNode[] links);
```

And call, but note: dbnode is not only Guid, it is more complicated class:

```
$bodyx = @{
                 "name"="zztop";"links"="[18220000-FA8F-40C5-8014-99044C6B1700]";"is_enabled"="0";
                }
                $jsonbody = $bodyx | ConvertTo-Json
                Write-Host $jsonbody
                Write-Host "========================"                    
                Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $url2 -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $jsonbody
```

Comment: Can you supply some more details about how you're hosting a REST service in a console application? If you're using some external hosting layer (IIS Express for example) and it's incorrectly configured then it's entirely possible for IIS Express to fail _before_ it reaches the point in the request pipeline where it would call the actual service...

Comment: I have a NET 4.8 Console application WCF: SOAP+Rest interfaces. My c# client calls this method and it works fine, but the Powershell call gives me an error. It seems the reason is   one of parameters: when I remove it from the call I see the method call in VS debugger. If I add it then receive the message above.  All simple parameters work fine but this MyMethod(MyObjects[], .... )  may be the problem. But how to understand what is incorrect? (I have added info to the `1st message)

Comment: Try running a dev proxy in the background (e.g. Fiddler) and hit the REST api with your C# client, then do the same with PowerShell, and compare the headers and body of the requests sent by both - that might help see what the difference is.